# Move a control from a method in Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms, function, position, label

High level question, is it possible to move a control from a method? Example, I have a `label` and a `button click event`, can the `label` move from one position `(X,Y)` to another from the button click to something like `(X+20,Y+20)`?

I haven't had any luck with changing the `.Position` property of the label, and I couldn't find anything online so I thought I would ask. Thanks!

EDIT: Was asked to show some code so here ya go. The label1.Position can't be selected/edited, and label1.Move is an event handler, for when the user moves the label?

```
private void MoveTextButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Position = (x,y);
        //label1.Move
    }
```

Comment: Answer: Yes. Show us what you've tried and we can help better.

Comment: Labels don't even have a `Position` property, where'd you get that from?  Try `Location`

Comment: You're right. I screwed up, think I saw Position on a different control and was wondering why I couldn't find it on a label. Thanks everyone for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change `Location` like :

```
   private void MoveTextButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       label1.Location = new Point(label1.Location.X + 20, label1.Location.Y + 20);
   }
```